# Understanding Ringdroid code + Android

Tags: java, android

This question is for those who are familiar with the Ringdroid code.
I am facing a bit difficulty in understanding '[CheapAMR.java](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/ringdroid/soundfile/CheapAMR.java)' file of Ringdroid [code](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/source/browse/#svn/trunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed). I have to implement this code in my Blackberry project, but first I want to understand the code properly.
I am not able to understand what's the use of following arrays in this file :

1. `int[] adaptiveIndex`
2. `int[] adaptiveGain`
3. `int[] fixedGain`
4. `int[][] pulse`

Also I am not able to understand how the values of these arrays are being filled. I am not getting any idea how to google for this issue since I am having no idea what they are doin in this code :

```
    void getMR122Params(int[] bits,
                            int[] adaptiveIndex,
                            int[] adaptiveGain,
                            int[] fixedGain,
                            int[][] pulse) {
            adaptiveIndex[0] =
                0x01 * bits[45] +
                0x02 * bits[43] +
                0x04 * bits[41] +
                0x08 * bits[39] +
                0x10 * bits[37] +
                0x20 * bits[35] +
                0x40 * bits[33] +
                0x80 * bits[31] +
                0x100 * bits[29];
            adaptiveIndex[1] =
                0x01 * bits[242] +
                0x02 * bits[79] +
                0x04 * bits[77] +
                0x08 * bits[75] +
                0x10 * bits[73] +
                0x20 * bits[71];
            adaptiveIndex[2] =
                0x01 * bits[46] +
                0x02 * bits[44] +
                0x04 * bits[42] +
                0x08 * bits[40] +
                0x10 * bits[38] +
                0x20 * bits[36] +
                0x40 * bits[34] +
                0x80 * bits[32] +
                0x100 * bits[30];
            adaptiveIndex[3] =
                0x01 * bits[243] +
                0x02 * bits[80] +
                0x04 * bits[78] +
                0x08 * bits[76] +
                0x10 * bits[74] +
                0x20 * bits[72];

            adaptiveGain[0] =
                0x01 * bits[88] +
                0x02 * bits[55] +
                0x04 * bits[51] +
                0x08 * bits[47];
            adaptiveGain[1] =
                0x01 * bits[89] +
                0x02 * bits[56] +
                0x04 * bits[52] +
                0x08 * bits[48];
            adaptiveGain[2] =
                0x01 * bits[90] +
                0x02 * bits[57] +
                0x04 * bits[53] +
                0x08 * bits[49];
            adaptiveGain[3] =
                0x01 * bits[91] +
                0x02 * bits[58] +
                0x04 * bits[54] +
                0x08 * bits[50];

            fixedGain[0] =
                0x01 * bits[104] +
                0x02 * bits[92] +
                0x04 * bits[67] +
                0x08 * bits[63] +
                0x10 * bits[59];
            fixedGain[1] =
                0x01 * bits[105] +
                0x02 * bits[93] +
                0x04 * bits[68] +
                0x08 * bits[64] +
                0x10 * bits[60];
            fixedGain[2] =
                0x01 * bits[106] +
                0x02 * bits[94] +
                0x04 * bits[69] +
                0x08 * bits[65] +
                0x10 * bits[61];
            fixedGain[3] =
                0x01 * bits[107] +
                0x02 * bits[95] +
                0x04 * bits[70] +
                0x08 * bits[66] +
                0x10 * bits[62];

            pulse[0][0] =
                0x01 * bits[122] +
                0x02 * bits[123] +
                0x04 * bits[124] +
                0x08 * bits[96];
            pulse[0][3] =
                0x01 * bits[125] +
                0x02 * bits[126] +
                0x04 * bits[127] +
                0x08 * bits[100];
            pulse[0][2] =
                0x01 * bits[128] +
                0x02 * bits[129] +
                0x04 * bits[130] +
                0x08 * bits[108];
            pulse[0][3] =
                0x01 * bits[131] +
                0x02 * 

bits[132] +
            0x04 * bits[133] +
            0x08 * bits[112];
        pulse[0][4] =
            0x01 * bits[134] +
            0x02 * bits[135] +
            0x04 * bits[136] +
            0x08 * bits[116];
        pulse[0][5] =
            0x01 * bits[182] +
            0x02 * bits[183] +
            0x04 * bits[184];
        pulse[0][6] =
            0x01 * bits[185] +
            0x02 * bits[186] +
            0x04 * bits[187];
        pulse[0][7] =
            0x01 * bits[188] +
            0x02 * bits[189] +
            0x04 * bits[190];
        pulse[0][8] =
            0x01 * bits[191] +
            0x02 * bits[192] +
            0x04 * bits[193];
        pulse[0][9] =
            0x01 * bits[194] +
            0x02 * bits[195] +
            0x04 * bits[196];
        pulse[1][0] =
            0x01 * bits[137] +
            0x02 * bits[138] +
            0x04 * bits[139] +
            0x08 * bits[97];
        pulse[1][4] =
            0x01 * bits[140] +
            0x02 * bits[141] +
            0x04 * bits[142] +
            0x08 * bits[101];
        pulse[1][2] =
            0x01 * bits[143] +
            0x02 * bits[144] +
            0x04 * bits[145] +
            0x08 * bits[109];
        pulse[1][3] =
            0x01 * bits[146] +
            0x02 * bits[147] +
            0x04 * bits[148] +
            0x08 * bits[113];
        pulse[1][4] =
            0x01 * bits[149] +
            0x02 * bits[150] +
            0x04 * bits[151] +
            0x08 * bits[117];
        pulse[1][5] =
            0x01 * bits[197] +
            0x02 * bits[198] +
            0x04 * bits[199];
        pulse[1][6] =
            0x01 * bits[200] +
            0x02 * bits[201] +
            0x04 * bits[202];
        pulse[1][7] =
            0x01 * bits[203] +
            0x02 * bits[204] +
            0x04 * bits[205];
        pulse[1][8] =
            0x01 * bits[206] +
            0x02 * bits[207] +
            0x04 * bits[208];
        pulse[1][9] =
            0x01 * bits[209] +
            0x02 * bits[210] +
            0x04 * bits[211];
        pulse[2][0] =
            0x01 * bits[152] +
            0x02 * bits[153] +
            0x04 * bits[154] +
            0x08 * bits[98];
        pulse[2][5] =
            0x01 * bits[155] +
            0x02 * bits[156] +
            0x04 * bits[157] +
            0x08 * bits[102];
        pulse[2][2] =
            0x01 * bits[158] +
            0x02 * bits[159] +
            0x04 * bits[160] +
            0x08 * bits[110];
        pulse[2][3] =
            0x01 * bits[161] +
            0x02 * bits[162] +
            0x04 * bits[163] +
            0x08 * bits[114];
        pulse[2][4] =
            0x01 * bits[164] +
            0x02 * bits[165] +
            0x04 * bits[166] +
            0x08 * bits[118];
        pulse[2][5] =
            0x01 * bits[212] +
            0x02 * bits[213] +
            0x04 * bits[214];
        pulse[2][6] =
            0x01 * bits[215] +
            0x02 * bits[216] +
            0x04 * bits[217];
        pulse[2][7] =
            0x01 * bits[218] +
            0x02 * bits[219] +
            0x04 * bits[220];
        pulse[2][8] =
            0x01 * bits[221] +
            0x02 * bits[222] +
            0x04 * bits[223];
        pulse[2][9] =
            0x01 * bits[224] +
            0x02 * bits[225] +
            0x04 * bits[226];
        pulse[3][0] =
            0x01 * bits[167] +
            0x02 * bits[168] +
            0x04 * bits[169] +
            0x08 * bits[99];
        pulse[3][6] =
            0x01 * bits[170] +
            0x02 * bits[171] +
            0x04 * bits[172] +
            0x08 * bits[103];
        pulse[3][2] =
            0x01 * bits[173] +
            0x02 * bits[174] +
            0x04 * bits[175] +
            0x08 * bits[111];
        pulse[3][3] =
            0x01 * bits[176] +
            0x02 * bits[177] +
            0x04 * bits[178] +
            0x08 * bits[115];
        pulse[3][4] =
            0x01 * bits[179] +
            0x02 * bits[180] +
            0x04 * bits[181] +
            0x08 * bits[119];
        pulse[3][5] =
            0x01 * bits[227] +
            0x02 * bits[228] +
            0x04 * bits[229];
        pulse[3][6] =
            0x01 * bits[230] +
            0x02 * bits[231] +
            0x04 * bits[232];
        pulse[3][7] =
            0x01 * bits[233] +
            0x02 * bits[234] +
            0x04 * bits[235];
        pulse[3][8] =
            0x01 * bits[236] +
            0x02 * bits[237] +
            0x04 * bits[238];
        pulse[3][9] =
            0x01 * bits[239] +
            0x02 * bits[240] +
            0x04 * bits[241];
    }
```

If any one has understanding of this then please help me also in understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation will be that the (input) bits array get distributed to the other (output) arrays, such way that certain "bit masks" in bits going into int values in the output arrays.

bits should contain only 0 and 1 at any index, then with this example

```
bits[88]=1;
bits[55]=0;
bits[51]=1;
bits[47]=0;

adaptiveGain[0] =
                0x01 * bits[88] +
                0x02 * bits[55] +
                0x04 * bits[51] +
                0x08 * bits[47];
```

adaptiveGain[0] will contain 1*1 + 0*2 + 1*4 + 0*8 = 5

Have in mind 0x is the hex notation. So 0x100 hex = 256 dec.

Comment: Thanx you very much for your explanation. This indeed has helped me in understanding what values are exactly going into these arrays. But I am not able to understand if they have taken indexes (88,55,51,47 etc) randomly or there is some specific information associated with these indexes.

Comment: Randomly for shure not. That must be an internal data representation, that i don't know. From the source it seems to be the decoding of one frame.